# u-boot cross compilation error

Tags: linux-kernel, linux-device-driver, u-boot

While compiling u-boot using following command

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

got an error quoting older version of GCC usage, as shown in attached screenshot.

But when I give path from gcc version greater than 6, using command shown below

```
make ARCH=arm CROSS_COMPILE=/home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

poped up an error as shown below:

```
./scripts/binutils-version.sh: line 18: /home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-as: No such file or directory
make: /home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: Command not found
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 25: /home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory
./scripts/gcc-version.sh: line 26: /home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc: No such file or directory
*** Your GCC does not produce working binaries in THUMB mode.
*** Your board is configured for THUMB mode.
arch/arm/config.mk:54: recipe for target 'checkthumb' failed
make: *** [checkthumb] Error 1
```

Also the bin file contains many `arm-linux-gnueabihf-gcc` exe, which one to be used

when I tried to export command, as shown below

```
export CC=/home/ubuntu/Software_ToolChain/gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf/bin/arm-linux-gnueabihf-
```

and checking the version `CC --version`, gives a error of "CC Command not found"

[find screen shot here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/l5Qtl.png)

Please help me on this.

Comment: Hello Pradeep, in the case the answer would have helped solving your problem, feel free to provide feedback since it may be helpful for others - thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are attempting to compile u-boot on a Ubuntu Linux system using a toolchain targeted for Windows/mingw32, i.e. `gcc-linaro-6.4.1-2017.11-i686-mingw32_arm-linux-gnueabihf`.

You should download a toolchain suitable for use on a Linux computer:
First, execute the following command on your ubuntu system:

```
uname -m
```

If the outcome is `i686`, download/install this [toolchain](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-i686_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz) from Linaro.
If the outcome is `x86_64`, download/install that [one](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/latest/arm-linux-gnueabihf/gcc-linaro-7.3.1-2018.05-x86_64_arm-linux-gnueabihf.tar.xz).

If you prefer an older version, look for the exact one you are looking for [here](https://releases.linaro.org/components/toolchain/binaries/).